# MYSQL time and date troubles

Tags: mysql, date, time

I am running a query to show upcoming events and selecting the events closest to the current date
and i am also sorting it on the basis of timing.

So suppose today's date is 18th july 2013, it is pulling out the top 3 events which are closest to july 18th .

SO if the event is on 22nd july 2013, it will select the three events and because of the AND in the query it is also checking for the timing of the event .

Now if the current time is 23:00 and the time of the event is 19:00 but event is on 22nd july it wont show that event because according to the query it should be greater than the curtime ..

SO how should i solve this problem..
THanks in advance

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE d_o_e>=CURDATE() AND t_o_e>=CURTIME() ORDER BY d_o_e ASC,t_o_e ASC LIMIT 3;";
```

Comment: Why don't you remove `AND t_o_e>=CURTIME()` from the query ?

Comment: If I remove it then the event which has already got over for the day will show...

Comment: so use `>` instead of `>=` with the date condition

Comment: then suppose u login on 20th july then the events for 20th july wont show...

Comment: So use: `$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE d_o_e>=NOW() ORDER BY d_o_e ASC,t_o_e ASC LIMIT 3;";`

Comment: You should really be storing date and time in the same column.

Comment: so i have to change the data type of d_o_e to datetime in mysql???

Comment: @alfasin Hey thanks it worked... You saved a lot of my time...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE d_o_e>=CURDATE() or
 ( d_o_e=CURDATE() and  t_o_e>=CURTIME() ) ORDER BY d_o_e ASC,t_o_e ASC                    LIMIT 3;";
```